# JavaScript Node.js Date Comparison and Array sort by Date

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

First, does JavaScript have no basic Date comparision the way Python might?

In my Node.js script, I have the following lines:

```
console.log(Date(2012,11,10) < Date(2012, 11, 9))
console.log(Date(2012,11,10) > Date(2012, 11, 9))
```

However, *both* of these lines return *false*.

It appears there are tons of questions about "Date Comparison in JavaScript".

However, for virtually all of them someone responds with their home-made solution for comparing dates, some of them quite long and/or "hacky".

Is there really no inherent or idiomatic way to simply compare dates in JavaScript.
Do any Node libraries support it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the `new` keyword

```
console.log(new Date(2012,11,10) < new Date(2012, 11, 9))
console.log(new Date(2012,11,10) > new Date(2012, 11, 9))
```

As [Elias Van Ootegem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1230836/elias-van-ootegem) pointed out it's a standard to return a string if the `new` keyword is omitted:

> When Date is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it returns a String representing the current time (UTC).
>
> NOTE
> The function call `Date(…)` is not equivalent to the object creation expression `new Date(…)` with the same arguments.

Source: [15.9.2 The Date Constructor Called as a Function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.2)

Comment: [not just Chrome 22](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.2), it's the language standard to return a string when the `new` keyword is omitted

Comment: @chrisco Use `var before = new Date(...)`. If you don't it will assign a string to `before` and not an date object.

Comment: But when I do this `new Date(2012,11,10) === new Date(2012,11,10)` I get `false`

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into date comparison problem myself, and though I can see @dev-null's answer does work for dates constructed as `new Date(2012,11,10)`, it doesn't seem work for parsed dates, at least in my case:

```
[vps@palladin]~$ node -v
v4.3.2
[vps@palladin]~$ node
> new Date('Wed Mar 09 2016 17:31:58 GMT-0800 (PST)') == new Date('Wed Mar 09 2016 17:31:58 GMT-0800 (PST)')
false
> new Date('Wed Mar 09 2016 17:31:58 GMT-0800 (PST)') < new Date('Wed Mar 09 2016 17:31:58 GMT-0800 (PST)')
false
> new Date('Wed Mar 09 2016 17:31:58 GMT-0800 (PST)') > new Date('Wed Mar 09 2016 17:31:58 GMT-0800 (PST)')
false
```

The only way that I found to reliably compare J/S Date objects is using `getTime()` function, and compare the results from both.

```
> new Date('Wed Mar 09 2016 17:31:58 GMT-0800 (PST)').getTime() == new Date('Wed Mar 09 2016 17:31:58 GMT-0800 (PST)').getTime()
true
> new Date('Wed Mar 09 2016 17:31:58 GMT-0800 (PST)').getTime() < new Date('Wed Mar 09 2016 17:31:58 GMT-0800 (PST)').getTime()
false
> new Date('Wed Mar 09 2016 17:31:58 GMT-0800 (PST)').getTime() > new Date('Wed Mar 09 2016 17:31:58 GMT-0800 (PST)').getTime()
false
```